# Combine two separate input fields in search with php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have two separate input fields that the one searches the surname and the other the name to search the db.

```
<li><label>Surname: </label><input type="text" name="surname" id="search_text" required autocomplete="off" /></li>
<li><label>Name:  </label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" required autocomplete="off"/></li>

    

<script> // first input live search 
            $(document).ready(function() {
        
        $("#search_text").keyup(function () {
                   var txt = $(this).val();  
                  
        setTimeout(function() { 
             if(txt.length>=3)  
                   {  
                        $.ajax({  
                             url:"fetchsurname.php",  
                             method:"post",  
                             data:{search:txt},  
                             dataType:"text",
                            
                             success:function(data)  
                             {  
                                  $('#searchresults').html(data);  
                             }  
                      });  
                   }  
                   else  
                   {  
                        $('#searchresults').html('');                 
                   }  
            }, 2000); // 1 sec delay to check.
        
            }); // End of  keyup function
        
            }); // End of document.ready

    </script>
<script> // second input live search    
    $(document).ready(function() {

$("#name").keyup(function () {
           var txt = $(this).val();  
          
setTimeout(function() { 
     if(txt.length>=3)  
           {  
                $.ajax({  
                     url:"fetchname.php",  
                     method:"post",  
                     data:{search:txt},  
                     dataType:"text",
                    
                     success:function(data)  
                     {  
                          $('#searchresults').html(data);  
                     }  
              });  
           }  
           else  
           {  
                $('#searchresults').html('');                 
           }  
    }, 2000); // 1 sec delay to check.

    }); // End of  keyup function

    }); // End of document.ready
</script>
```

That searches the db with two separate files of php fetchname and fetchsuurname

> "SELECT * FROM base WHERE name LIKE '".$_POST["search"]."%'"
>
> "SELECT * FROM base WHERE surname LIKE '".$_POST["search"]."%'"

My problem is that every field is searching its own value in the tables and not combined with the first field to show the results .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your html, you should change jQuery and to following code:

```
<li><label>Surname: </label><input type="text" name="surname" id="search_text" required autocomplete="off" /></li>

<li><label>Name:  </label><input type="text" name="name" id="search_name" required autocomplete="off"/></li>

<script> // first input live search 
var keyupfunction = function () {
        var search_text = $("#search_text").val();  
        var search_name = $("#search_name").val();  

        setTimeout(function() { 
            if(txt.length>=3)  
            {  
                $.ajax({  
                    url:"fetchsurname.php",  
                    method:"post",  
                    data:{"surname":search_text, "name":search_name},  
                    dataType:"text",

                    success:function(data)  
                    {  
                        $('#searchresults').html(data);  
                    }  
                });  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                $('#searchresults').html('');                 
            }  
        }, 2000); // 1 sec delay to check.

    }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#search_text").keyup(keyupfunction); 
    $("#search_name").keyup(keyupfunction); 
});
```

you can use from or in your queries:

```
SELECT * FROM base WHERE name LIKE '".$_POST["name"]."%' AND surname LIKE '".$_POST["surname"]."%'
```

also you can use from Or if you do not want both of fields have value

also there are another solution which you can union 2 select for 2 different table

```
SELECT * FROM base WHERE name LIKE '".$_POST["name"]."%'
union all
SELECT * FROM base WHERE surname LIKE '".$_POST["surname"]."%'
```

Comment: am I changing something also in ajax search?

Comment: no you should change your query with first one, second one is for times which you want to have result from two different table

Comment: it doesn't work now every input field searches for the surname or the name separately . I want the second field named "name" to take the value of the first and search only the name that matches the first eg. if surname is Gates the second field should search for Bill and the result to be Bill Gates . Now the first field it show's every person that has surname or name Gates and the second also every person that has surname or name Bill

Comment: please add your html to your question

Comment: In case you want result like Bill Gates, you have to combine the result with AND in fist query, like
SELECT * FROM base WHERE name LIKE '".$_POST["search"]."%' AND surname LIKE '".$_POST["search"]."%'

Comment: the two inputs don't combine to each other and in the results now shows nothing

Comment: according to html which you sent you should change javascript code and query. i will edit my post soon